# One dimensional wave equation - getting slightly different result

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, wave-equation

Consider the one dimensional wave equation
$$
u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}
$$
where the initial conditions are
$$
\begin{cases}
u(x,0) = Ax\\
u_x(0,t)=u_x(L,t)=0.
\end{cases}
$$
With separation of variables $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, I obtain:

$$X=B\cos([\sqrt{\lambda}]x)$$

and

$$-[\sqrt{\lambda}]B\sin([\sqrt{\lambda}]L)= 0.$$

We get
$$[\sqrt{\lambda}]=2n\pi/L$$

However, the answer states that it has to be $(2n-1)$ instead of $2n$ which suggests that a $-1$ value for the cosine value is required for the given situation.

I'm wondering what I've missed to not get the correct value.

Thank you for your time.

I do not know how to use mathjax so I will state the answer below in image format:

[answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAqt6.png)
Thanks again.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your equations.

Comment: Please show a print of the answer.

Comment: If $\sin(\sqrt\lambda L) = 0$, then permitted eigenvalues are $\sqrt \lambda = n\pi/L$ for both even and odd $n$.  If the final answer only has odd $n$, then it must be that those are the only nonzero coefficients that are present after applying the initial conditions (you are also missing one initial condition).